# TextBox.text value not updated when page is not refreshed

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a textBox (tbAdresse) which doesn't have any value. Then I do this in javascript :

```
 origin = document.getElementById("tbAdresse").value;
        if (origin == "")
            origin = <%=this.GetFormatStringCoordonnees("Paris")%>;                   
        else
            origin = <%=this.GetFormatStringCoordonnees(tbAdresse.Text)%>;
```

In this code, on first Load origin equals to "" which is correct. When I write "something" in tbAdresse origin = "something" too so its ok. But in the else statement, tbAdresse.Text seems to always be equal to "".

I'm never refreshing the page while doing this and I think it's the reason why it's not working but I really don't get why. Can I update tbAdresse.Text to its actual value without refreshing the page ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you not mean to do this:

```
 origin = document.getElementById("tbAdresse").value;
        if (origin == "")
            origin = <%=this.GetFormatStringCoordonnees("Paris")%>;                   
        else
            origin = <%=this.GetFormatStringCoordonnees(origin)%>;
```

If not, please post some more details on what your the elements and functions actually are.